# How to create an array of parent class variable as a private member in the inheriting class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, pointers, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a matrix class where every member is a fraction; instead of a float or an int. Here is the code for the fraction class.
fraction.h

```
class fraction{
private:
    int num, den;
public:
    fraction();
    fraction(int, int);
    fraction& operator=(const fraction&);
};
```

Fraction.cpp

```
#include "fraction.h"

fraction::fraction(){
   num = 0;
   den = 0;
}

fraction::fraction(int a, int b){
   num = a;
   den = b;
}
fraction& fraction::operator=(const fraction& lhs){
   num = lhs.num;
   den = lhs.den;
   return *this;
}
```

I am declaring matrix class as below.

```
#include "fraction.h"
class matrix:public fraction{
private:
   fraction **mt(int, int);
   fraction **unity(int, int);
   int sz;
public:
   matrix();
   matrix(fraction**, int);
   ~matrix();
};
```

How can I initialize the matrix class? I tried many things but none of them seems to work. These pointers just do not accept any values.

Comment: Inheritance implies "is a" relationship.  Is a matrix a fraction?

Comment: Your copy constructor and copy-assignment operator are **100%** unnecessary -- they do exactly what the implicitly-declared copy constructor and copy-assigment operator would do, only possibly less efficiently.

Comment: Why do people love inheritance so much? Composition > inheritance 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pointers in the Matrix class you defined. Also, there is no reason to inherit from Fraction (Matrix contains fractions, but it is not a fraction itself).

To avoid pointers you can use C++ vectors, however they are one dimensional, so one strategy could be to linearize the matrix into a vector.

```
#include <vector>

class Matrix {   // does *not* inherit from fraction!
  private:
    int rows_;
    int cols_;
    std::vector<Fraction> data_;

  public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols) : rows_(rows), cols_(cols),
                                 data_(rows * cols) {}

    const Fraction& operator()(int i, int j) const {
      assert(0 <= i && i < rows_);
      assert(0 <= j && j < cols_);
      return data[i * cols_ + j];
    } 
};

Matrix m(5, 8);
cout << m(3, 1);
```

Comment: Edited to avoid getting into this rat hole: new[] only gets a single argument: the array size. The language leaves it up to the user to figure out how to dynamically allocate multidimensional arrays (arrays of arrays, linearization, etc).

Comment: I am looking for pointers. If I linearize a matrix into a vector, matrix operations will not be quite intuitive. BTW, what is so wrong about pointers to fraction class? I want to use them because operator overloading easier.

Comment: I don't see the connection you are making between operator overloading and pointers.

The interface that the Matrix class exposing to its users (overloaded operators) has nothing to do with the way it stores the data internally (linearization). Those two things can be changed independently. I edited the sample to use operator() for getting elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to init twoD array pointer like **mt twice: first, every row; second, in every row, init column

Comment: I just don't get what you are trying to say. Did you even read the question? I tried to initialize fraction class with 2D pointer in the matrix.cpp and every time I was getting errors.

Comment: I use  fraction **mt; instead of  fraction **mt(int, int); and use following to init.   int size = 10;
  mt = new fraction*[size*size];
  for(int row = 0; row < size; ++row){
   mt[row] = new fraction[size];
  }